# Update Background Color of Checkbox in PySimpleGuiQT

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, checkbox, pysimplegui

Im trying to update the background color of my checkbox when it is clicked. However, the moment i call the update method, somehow another event on the same element is triggered, resulting in unexpected behavior. Can somebody tell me how to achieve that?!

My minimal Code is as follows:

```
import PySimpleGUIQt as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Checkbox('test', enable_events=True, key='test', background_color="green",default=True)]
]

window = sg.Window('Sample GUI', layout, finalize=True)
while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "test":
        if not values[event]:
            window[event].update(background_color="red")
        else:
            window[event].update(background_color="green")

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt port is still under revision, not everything work fine.

Try also to set the `value` at the same time for the checkbox when you set the `background_color`.

```py
import PySimpleGUIQt as sg

layout = [[sg.Checkbox('test', enable_events=True, key='test', background_color="green",default=True)]]
window = sg.Window('Sample GUI', layout, finalize=True)

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "test":
        value = values[event]
        if not value:
            window[event].update(value=value, background_color="red")
        else:
            window[event].update(value=value, background_color="green")

window.close()
```

Comment: Perfect - that was it!!!